# Too small sigma when fitting a 2D Gaussian

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am doing some work which requires fitting a Gaussian to a cluster of points which is expected to be distributed normally.

I have data which looks like this, you can see the small tightly grouped cluster of points on the left:

[image]

I zoom in around the cluster, and use scikit-learn KDE to get a density distribution (with Gaussian kernel), which looks like this:

[image]

Then I fit the Gaussian and it turns out to have far too small sigma:

```
centroid_x: -36.3204357 
centroid_y: -12.8734763
sigma_x:     0.17916588
sigma_y:     0.07428976
```

[image]

From inspection of the density distribution, the x and y sigma should be more on the order of ~1, rather than ~0.1. Does anyone know why this behaviour might be occurring? I don't believe there are significant errors in my code or method, this technique has worked well on other data sets, for example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you using to fit the gaussian? Sklearn? Custom code?

Comment: um, how could we possibly know why you get a result when you posted no code at all showing what you did?  You went to the trouble to add 6 images to your question and yet not a single line of code.  Post a minimal complete example that shows what you did.